# ComboBox and dojo.store via ajax

Tags: combobox, dojo

I have a ComboBox and I'd like to fetch data from server first when user type at least 3 characters.

I've used `dojo.data.*` but it's deprecated and I cannot find something similar in `dojo.store.*` and `xhr|ajax` in one sentence. Do you have some tips?

I use declarative markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used the `dojox/data/QueryReadStore`? There is no similar store at the moment I think. The best alternative you have (with the `dojo/store` API) is the [JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) store.

But it isn't exactly the same, so you might have to extend it. You should probably start by looking at both API's (the old and the new API) and compare the `dojox/data/QueryReadStore` and the `dojo/store/JsonRest` to successfully extend it.

Comment: Yes I used to use dojox.data.QueryReadStore. It seems it's not deprecated (yet), so I will go for it.

Comment: In 2.0 the DojoX library will disappear. I think it's not clear yet which module will survive and which will be abandoned.
Also, it extends two deprecated API's (`dojo/data/api/Read` and `dojo/data/api/Identity`), so saying it's not deprecated is not entirely true ;)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, I havent knew that... Well, currently I have no choice so I will have to use that :(

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552872/override-a-method-in-dojo-dojo-store-memory

Comment: How do you mean? He says you need the JsonRest store. I also said that in my answer.