# Override a method in dojo - dojo.store.Memory

Tags: dojo

Is there a way how to run my own function before a dojo method is spawned?

Specifically I need to refresh data in dojo.store.Memory before query() function is spawned. My idea is to put there a callback (that will be spawned before query()), fetch new data from server and then set the data to Memory instance. Then just call

```
this.inherited(arguments)
```

I've tried override query method with declare, but I'm still getting some unrelated errors. 4 hours but no luck...

Is there a another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can fire callbacks before, after or around any method. Just use [dojo/aspect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/aspect.html)

Something like this should work :

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/aspect"], function(Memory, aspect){
    aspect.before(Memory, "query", function(){
        // do something
    });
});
```

However, for your specific use case, if I understood correctly, what you want is to have a store linked to a server-side controller. In that case, you should use [dojo/store/JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) rather than dojo/store/Memory. No need to fire any methods before the query...

Comment: I used dojo/store/JsonRest. Thanks.